# ControlTemplate with DataTrigger Vs. DataTemplate with DataTemplateSelector

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatemplate, controltemplate

I have a generic control which displays an editor based on the type property inside a ViewModel. Currently it's implemented using `Control`, `ControlTemplate` and `DataTrigger` like this -

```
<Control
   x:Name="MainControl"
   Grid.Column="1"
   TargetUpdated="OnTargetUpdated">
        <Control.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding Path=EditorType}"
                        Value="{x:Static view:EditorType.Bool}">
                        <Setter
                            Property="Control.Template"
                            Value="{StaticResource boolTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding Path=EditorType}"
                        Value="{x:Static view:EditorType.Text}">
                        <Setter
                            Property="Control.Template"
                            Value="{StaticResource textTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding Path=EditorType}"
                        Value="{x:Static view:EditorType.Integer}">
                        <Setter
                            Property="Control.Template"
                            Value="{StaticResource integerTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    ...
                    ...
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
     </Control.Style>
</Control>
```

Now, same can be achieved using `ContentPresenter`, `DataTemplate` and `DataTemplateSelector` like this -

```
<local:EditorTemplateSelector
    BoolEditorTemplate="{StaticResource boolTemplate}"
    TextEditorTemplate="{StaticResource textTemplate}"
    IntegerEditorTemplate="{StaticResource integerTemplate}"
    ...
    ...
    x:Key="EditorTemplateSelector">
</local:EditorTemplateSelector>

<ContentPresenter
    ContentTemplateSelector="{Binding Source={StaticResource EditorTemplateSelector}}"
    Content="{Binding}"
    TargetUpdated="OnTargetUpdated">
</ContentPresenter>

// Template selector returning appropriate template based on type
```

I feel the second approach, using `DataTemplateSelector` is better but would like to know from you -

- Which one is better and why?
- Will there be any performance difference in two?

Comment: From what i gather, the second way is considered best practice. It also much more readable since it doesn't hold the logic of selection (which should always be defined in C#). However I'm interested as well on the performance point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've heard that `DataTemplateSelectors` do not update the template if the value they're based on changes, and because of this I usually don't use them.

My preferred method is actually to use DataTemplates.

```
<MyControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:BooleanModel}">
        <local:BooleanView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:IntegerModel}">
        <local:IntegerView />
    </DataTemplate>
    ...
</MyControl.Resources>
```

Second, if I want to change the template based on a property rather than the object type, I tend to use `DataTriggers`. This is because if that property ever gets changed, the PropertyChange notification will automatically tell the UI that it has changed and to update the template. I do not believe `DataTemplateSelectors` do this automatically. I also prefer to see the template selection logic in my XAML, not have it hidden in a TemplateSelector file, but that's just personal preference.

And my last choice is to use a `DataTemplateSelector`. I almost never use one in a WPF application, although I often do in Silverlight since it doesn't support my preferred method of using implicit `DataTemplates` (yet)

I am not aware of any significant performance differences between the two, although I would be interested if someone can tell me otherwise.

Comment: Interesting, I'm almost sure the question was about WPF, just out of curiosity - did they fix up implicit templates in SL4/5 as I know they weren't available in the prev versions.

Comment: @Dmitry I believe the last Silverlight project I did was in 4.0, and implicit DataTemplates didn't work then. I heard they work in 5.0, but haven't it yet.

Comment: +1 for 'DataTemplateSelectors do not update the template if the value they're based on chan'. I checked this and the template doesn't update if value changes. thanks.

Comment: That's not always true. If you have a ContentPresenter with Content={Binding Path=SomeProp} then if SomeProp changes the ContentPresenter will ask the TemplateSelector for the template again. However if SomeProp does NOT change but a property of that object changes then you won't get a call to the template selector again.

Comment: Here is datatemplateselector exmaple from @Rachel [change-data-template-dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136816/change-data-template-dynamically)

Answer (score 3):

You've two questions here:)

1. Where to make a decsion in `XAML`(`DataTriggers`) or in code `TemplateSelector`
2. What are you overriding the whole `Style` or just the `DataTemplate`. In your first sample you override `Style`, in the second one - `DataTemplate`.

Here're my 2c:

I'd stick with the Triggers, as you'll get an unbeatable flexibility level with them - a new editor for the price of new resource and a trigger all in XAML - what can be better? There's one potential caveat, related to DataTrigger usage - it may cause data leaks.

Talking of `Style` vs `DataTemplate` choice I's stick again with the `Style`. It might be a bit heavier visual tree wise, but it'll give you the ultimate control over the apperance of you editors.

In particular, some properties can only be defined at a `Style` level, using `Style` `Setters`'s.
Defining then @`DataTemplate` level simply won't work as your `DataTemplate` content is not an immediate child of your control container (there's an extra level - the actula Control). If you've no such properties, `ControlTemplates` are good too, and probably faster(?).

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, can you provide more details about 'DataTrigger causing data leaks'?

Comment: @akjoshi - Sorry I won't be able to come up with a exact repro, this is rather an observation, I've seen a few projects which benefit grately after reducing the number of triggers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also not a fan of DataTemplateSelector, but I guess you could use them if your selector-evaluation consists of **more than type checking**, e.g. `if x>5 && dayOfWeek==Tue && isFullMoon(today)` then template1.

Comment: Yes, if complex logic is required then DataTemplateSelector is useful; although some cases can still be achieved through MultiDataTrigger too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the answer is more one of do you think a `control` is necessary. You get a whole bunch of functionality with a `control` that is not really available with a `DataTemplate`. You can add `DependencyProperties`, `events`, `functions` etc etc. But do you need this? If you don't then a control might be overkill.