# Change Data template dynamically

Tags: wpf, triggers, datatemplateselector, datatemplate

I have a item control which is bound to Tasks. Each task has task state. I have defined different data templates for each task state, and also data template selector.

Problem is that I am not able to figure out how to trigger data template selector when task state is changed dynamically.

**I want to know how to use data triggers together with data templates.**

If this will not work out, i will explore other alternatives such as
1. Attached Property bound to task state. Any change will dynamically set data template.
2. Visual State Manager

Comment: maybe this answer will fit also for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715315/how-to-trigger-datatemplateselector-when-property-changes

Comment: Looked at this answer already. This may work, but looks a bit complex. Looking for simpler solution.

Comment: The question maybe duplicated with [how-to-trigger-datatemplateselector-when-property-changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715315/how-to-trigger-datatemplateselector-when-property-changes) and [ControlTemplate with DataTrigger Vs. DataTemplate with DataTemplateSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926024/controltemplate-with-datatrigger-vs-datatemplate-with-datatemplateselector)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

A `DataTemplateSelector` does not respond to `PropertyChange` notifications, so it doesn't get re-evaluated when your properties change.

The alternative I use is `DataTriggers` that changes the `Template` based on a property.

For example, this will draw all `TaskModel` objects using a `ContentControl`, and the `ContentControl.Template` is based on the `TaskStatus` property of the `TaskModel`

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OpenTaskTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:TaskModel}">
     <TextBlock Text="I'm an Open Task" />
</DataTemplate> 

<DataTemplate x:Key="ClosedTaskTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:TaskModel}">
     <TextBlock Text="I'm a Closed Task" />
 </DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TaskModel}">
     <ContentControl Content="{Binding }">
         <ContentControl.Style>
             <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">

                 <!-- Default Template -->
                 <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource OpenTaskTemplate}" />

                 <!-- Triggers to change Template -->
                 <Style.Triggers>
                     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TaskStatus}" Value="Closed">
                         <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ClosedTaskTemplate}" />
                     </DataTrigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
             </Style>
         </ContentControl.Style>
     </ContentControl>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: hmm, DataTemplate doesn't seem have a targetType member.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @JakeGaston Are you using Silverlight? I don't think implicit DataTemplates (ones with only TargetType set) are implemented in Silverlight until 4.5.

Answer (score 8):

Just a quick note for anyone that found this incredibly helpful as I did -

Currently with WPF, it looks like you'll want to use **DataType** rather than **TargetType** on your DataTemplate definitions:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OpenTaskTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:TaskModel}">
     <TextBlock Text="I'm an Open Task" />
</DataTemplate> 

<DataTemplate x:Key="ClosedTaskTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:TaskModel}">
     <TextBlock Text="I'm a Closed Task" />
 </DataTemplate>
```