# WPF change main window view from inside a UserControl with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

Im currently trying to learn WPF and the MVVM pattern, but am confused when it comes to changing the main windows view from inside a User Control.

**What I currently have**

I have a single window application which when started displays a login view which is a UserControl and is set as a ContentControl in my main window.

*ApplicationView.xaml*

```
    <Window x:Class="MyApplication.Views.ApplicationView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Views"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApplication.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        DataContext="{Binding Application, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">    
   <Window.Resources>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:LoginViewModel }">
            <local:LoginView />
        </DataTemplate>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:MainViewViewModel }">
           <local:MainView />
       </DataTemplate>
   </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}"></ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*ApplicationViewModel.cs*

```
namespace MyApplication.ViewModels
{
    public class ApplicationViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Fields

        private ICommand _changePageCommand;
        private IPageViewModel _currentPageViewModel;
        private List<IPageViewModel> _pageViewModels;

        #endregion

        public ApplicationViewModel()
        {
            //Add available pages
            PageViewModels.Add(new LoginViewModel());
            PageViewModels.Add(new MainViewViewModel());

            //Set starting page
            CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels[0];

        }

        #region Properties / Commands

        public ICommand ChangePageCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_changePageCommand == null)
                {
                    _changePageCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(
                        p => ChangeViewModel((IPageViewModel)p),
                        p => p is IPageViewModel);
                }

                return _changePageCommand;
            }
        }

        public List<IPageViewModel> PageViewModels
        {
            get
            {
                if (_pageViewModels == null)                
                    _pageViewModels = new List<IPageViewModel>();

                return _pageViewModels;
            }
        }

        public IPageViewModel CurrentPageViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentPageViewModel;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_currentPageViewModel != value)
                {
                    _currentPageViewModel = value;
                    this.VerifyPropertyName("CurrentPageViewModel");
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion


        #region Methods
        private void ChangeViewModel(IPageViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (!PageViewModels.Contains(viewModel))
                PageViewModels.Add(viewModel);

            CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels
                .FirstOrDefault(vm => vm == viewModel);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**What I want to achieve**

I want to change the applications window view from the LoginView to the MainView once a login button inside the login UserControl is clicked. I'm struggling to get my head around how this would be possible and how to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the following link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136816/change-data-template-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to execute the `Command` in the `ApplicationViewModel` from your `UserControl`.  Consider you have a `Button` on your `UserControl` that need to switch view in main window on clicking, you can trigger it as follows

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource=
          {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ApplicationViewModel}}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

If you need full working example, you can refer [WPF MVVM navigate views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19654812/2819451)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**In Application View.xaml :**

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}"></ContentControl>
```

In **loginview.xaml**, bind the login button click to a command inside LoginViewModel as `LoginButtonClickedCommand`

Listen to the command in **ApplicationViewModel**

```
LoginViewModelInstance.LoginButtonClickedCommand = new RelayCommand(OnLoginButtonClicked, param => true);
```

Handle the command handler and change the CurrentPageViewModel inside ApplicationViewModel

```
private void OnLoginButtonClicked(object obj)
{
    CurrentPageViewModel = new ContentPageViewModel();
}
```

This should do the trick for you.

Comment: I thought the `CurrentPageViewModel` is already set within the method `ChangeViewModel`?

Comment: @KevinWallis: I was saying about the new **ContentPageViewModel** which he wants to transit to when user clicks on login button. I am afraid, he has not included the new **ContentPageViewModel** in the list of ViewModels that he is currently maintaining inside the application page.