# WPF: Change the user control programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF, I  wanted to display a window with multiple user controls.

**example.xaml**

```
<DockPanel>

<Border x:Name ="TopRegion" DockPanel.Dock = "top">
    <local:userControl1/>
 </Border>

<Border x:Name ="leftRegion" DockPanel.Dock = "left">
    <local:userControl2/>
 </Border>

</DockPanel>
```

The usercontrol1 and usercontrol2 are other views in the same  project. I.e usercontrol1.xaml and usercontrol2.xaml.

Problem is that i need to change the `usercontrol` of  `leftRegion` from `usercontrol2` to `usercontrol3` during run time i.e programatically.

How to achieve this in example.xaml.cs program.

Comment: Whenever you say WPF you also have to say MVVM too. WPF has some very powerful features as datatemplates and templateselectors which are best used with MVVM

Comment: In any of the XAML-based APIs, such as WPF, the moment you say you want to change a UI object directly via programmatic means, you have failed. You haven't provided enough context (i.e. a good [mcve], along with supporting details), but ...

Comment: ... the scenario you appear to be trying to address is much better addressed by defining view model classes for each `UserControl` you want to display, declaring `DataTemplate` resources for each of those view model classes, where the template contains simply the `UserControl` you want associated with that view model class, and the use `ContentControl` to present the view model, letting WPF do the work of matching the view model to the right `UserControl`. Then, changing the displayed `UserControl` is a simple matter of changing the view model class you're using in that spot.

Comment: Sorry, I will take care of this next time.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, you know the job, I agree with you but as you can see my answer that says this and offers one possible solution was twice downvoted, even marked for deleting by some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already named the `Border` *leftRegion*, so you could use this `Border` to set a new child like

```
leftRegion.Child = new userControl3();
```

programatically in code behind.

This means you are replacing the instance of `userControl2` of the `Border` with a new instance of `userControl3`.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Please provide me some document links to data template, user control, dynamically changing the User controls.

Comment: You can find a short introduction to datatemplates at https://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html and a way to change datatemplates dynamically at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136816/change-data-template-dynamically or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146269/change-wpf-datatemplate-for-listbox-item-if-selected . Note that this is a totally different approach to solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

While this is a legitimate request, it crosses with the logic of XAML and data binding, so I would suggest an alternative way that will have the same effect for end-user but is more in the spirit of XAML.

The solution is simple - just have both controls in your XAML and switch their `Visibility` based on whether you need one or another control to be displayed.