# wpf Get object type in xaml triggers

Tags: wpf, triggers, datatrigger

I often use triggers that depend on local class types. Common case are general control styles, which have class-dependent ContentControls.
Scenario:

1) A UserControl that implements a listbox 'MyUserControl'

2) A large listbox style, that applies to a Listbox Control inside the Usercontrol. The style has an initially empty ContentControl (that is filled with a Label / StackPanel)

```
<ContentControl Name="SpecificLabel"></ContentControl>
```

3) There are Contentcontrols defined for each specific derived class

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="listbox1Template">
    <Label...
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="listbox2Template">
    <StackPanel...
</ControlTemplate>
```

4) Depending on the derived class of MyListboxControl, the template of the contentcontrol is chosen by Datatriggers:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=DataType}" Value="{x:Type local:MyListbox1}">
    <Setter TargetName="SpecificLabel" Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource listbox1template}"/>
</DataTrigger>

<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=DataType}" Value="{x:Type local:MyListbox2}">
    <Setter TargetName="SpecificLabel" Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource listbox2template}"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Therefore, the base class offers a DataType property:

```
public Type DataType
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetType();
    }
}
```

This looks that there must be simpler ways. Is it possible to get the local type in XAML only, without using this property ?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [DataTemplate.DataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx) property and let WPF doing the work.No Triggers, no additional DataType property.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyListbox1}">
    <Label...
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: In the example above, I use an empty ContentControl, and insert the template via the datatriggers. So what's not clear to me: How would you insert this datatemplate in the listbox style ?

Comment: ...additionally, I don't want to code a c# coded template selector. So what's the secret ?

Comment: You don't need a template selector. Everytime WPF has to display one of your local classes it will use the specified DataTemplate. I don't know your code but in your case I assume you can bind ContentControl.Content with `{Binding}` and according to the type of `this` it should choose the right listbox DataTemplate.

Comment: Sounds plausible. But the Content={Binding} won't do the job. I tried to set "Template" or "ContentTemplate" property. This always works out to need a selector! [please see this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926024/controltemplate-with-datatrigger-vs-datatemplate-with-datatemplateselector/8927226#8927226) it shows the problem I don't get. Could you provide a piece of code ?

Comment: Maybe you can first simplify your code. It should be enough to add two DataTemplates with differently styled listboxes for your local:MyListbox classes to UserControl.Resources and bind your data to a ContentControl in your UserControl. Without the DataTemplates it should only show the class name like in this example [A Guided Tour of WPF – Part 4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18303/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-4-Data-templates-and-tri) (see section *Without a DataTemplate*). If not your binding is not correct. But with the DataTemplates the ContentControl knows how to render your classes.